# Does the timing of cycle-walking pose a threat?

Tags: cryptanalysis, timing-attack, format-preserving

Cycle-walking is a technique for format-preserving encryption that involves repeating an encryption process until the result is inside a desired range.

For example, given an input P, a range R, and an encryption function E.

```
C := E(P)
Is C in R?
  yes?
    Output C and quit
  no?
    C := E(C)
    Try again
```

My question is, does the variable timing of this pose a threat? It isn't constant time, but the time is dependant on `E(P)`, which in theory shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: Is that really a useful thing? Assuming E has good properties, the expected number of cycles is going to be 2^blocksize / size of R, which is going to be impractically large in all but a very few (artificial-feeling) cases.

Comment: @Rup A block cipher of an arbitrary size can be constructed from a fixed block cipher using various means, bringing the chance of a success to at least 50%. And anyway [I didn't come up with this idea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Format-preserving_encryption#FPE_from_cycle_walking), I'm just asking about it's properties.

Comment: The important thing here is not the number of cycles, but rather the average cycle length. Using the OP's notation, if the domain of the original cipher $E$ is not "very much" bigger than the set $R$ the average number of iterations is small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intuition is correct: the timing channel in cycle walking does not affect the *pseudorandom permutation* (PRP) security of a format-preserving encryption scheme built using cycle walking.

More precisely, it is possible to prove that any FPE scheme which meets PRP security in the standard sense also meets a stronger notion of PRP security in which the time taken to encrypt a point is given to the adversary. Intuitively, this is because the distribution of cycle lengths for a random permutation can be simulated given only the size of the domain. See section 9 of [the original FPE paper.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/251.pdf)